# Rails 3 - How to order a simple query by a date field?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I do a simple order by a date field?

```
user.projects.order("quote_sheet_generated").each do |project|
```

This doesn't work.  It displays the projects, but not ordered by the quote_sheet_generated field.

Answer (score 0):

sure it does, see the guides on this topic: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering